# Playwright locator.evaluateAll how to return map filled using nodes forEach

Tags: javascript, eval, playwright

I want to grab properties of all `<custom-tag>` nodes and the innerText of a node-child either of type `<custom-text>` or of type `<custom-number>`

A simplified version in the devtools is this

```js
const headersMap = new Map();
var headers = Object.create(null);
document.querySelectorAll("h2").forEach(el => {
    
    headers[el.id] = el.innerText
    headersMap.set(el.id, el.innerText)    
});
console.log("h2 count > 2 === " , (headersMap.size>2))
console.table(Array.from(headersMap, ([name, value]) => ({ name, value })));
```

For the [API testing page](https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing) this looks like this

[image: console output from code above]

This is my playwright attempt

```js
test('API Testing - H2 count greater than 2', async ({ }) => {     
    await test.step('API Testing - get titles', async() => {

        await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing');
        
        const headersList = await page.locator('h2');
        var headersMap = await headersList.evaluateAll(node => {
            const headersMap = new Map();
            var headers = Object.create(null);
            headers[node.id] = node.innerText
            headersMap.set(node.id, node.innerText)    
            return headersMap;
        });
        await expect(headersMap.size).toBeGreaterThan(2);
        page.pause();
        
    });
});
```

But it reports:

```bash
   Error: expect(received).toBeGreaterThan(expected)
   Matcher error: received value must be a number or bigint
   Received has value: undefined
      47 |             return headersMap;
      48 |         });
    > 49 |         await expect(headersMap.size).toBeGreaterThan(2);
         |                                       ^
      50 |         page.pause();
```

#### Question

- How can i create an object fill it with forEach and return it?
- What must be changed that `my_locator.evaluateAll()` returns a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`locator.evaluateAll()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-evaluate-all), you get an array in the callback. I'd call the parameter `nodes` rather than `node` so you're clear that you'll need to iterate it.

Second problem: maps aren't easily serializable. Try it:

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set("hello", "world");
console.log(m.get("hello")); // => "world"
console.log(JSON.stringify(m)); // => {}
```

All data passed to and from `evaluate` calls will be de/serialized, which will destroy your map. Unless you have some compelling reason to use a map, I'd just use a plain old object.

Here's one option:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test("playwright docs page has correct headers", async ({page}) => {
  const url = "https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const headers = await page.locator("h2").evaluateAll(nodes =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      nodes.map(node => [node.id, node.textContent.trim()])
    )
  );
  const expected = {
    "writing-api-test": "Writing API Test​",
    "using-request-context": "Using request context​",
    "sending-api-requests-from-ui-tests": "Sending API requests from UI tests​",
    "reusing-authentication-state": "Reusing authentication state​",
    "context-request-vs-global-request": "Context request vs global request​",
  };
  expect(headers).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Note that you don't need to `await` a locator definition, only an action. Usually use `.textContent` rather than `.innerText`. Trim your HTML strings to normalize them. Watch out for the funny `​&ZeroWidthSpace;`s in those headers (consider grabbing only the text node and ignoring the `<a>`). No need to `await` a non-locator assertion.

All that said, the approach above isn't exactly best practice since it doesn't use a [web first](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions) assertion. I'd rewrite it to use `.toHaveText()` on the locator directly.

```js
await expect(page.locator("h2")).toHaveText([
  "Writing API Test​",
  "Using request context​",
  "Sending API requests from UI tests​",
  "Reusing authentication state​",
  "Context request vs global request​",
]);
```

The ids can be tested separately and may not really matter that much anyway. You can [poll](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#polling) or [retry](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#retrying) to wait for the predicate to be true as a last resort, but if you're sure these are always on the page statically, it's probably OK to break the web-first rule.

Comment: Regarding `Unless you have some compelling reason to use a map, I'd just use a plain old object`. Would an array of objects be ok as well? For my use case i have something similar to an  `order` with  `order line items`. I want to test if a price increase works as expected for attributes of the line item (`single price`, `line item total`, `price increased absolut`, `price increased percent`) and for some attributes of the order (`total sum` is increased). I want to test if the price increase logic works as expected: `orderBeforePriceIncrease * price_increase = orderAfterPriceIncrease`

Comment: I still not understand how to return an array of objects or why in my updated code `lineItems` is undefined.

Comment: Apples and oranges, after the update. Arrays of objects are serializable, but you inadvertently created a new problem. The codepen site has an iframe, so you'll need to expand the iframe to query it, or use https://cdpn.io/codemuggle/fullpage/dygJLLV?anon=true&view=fullpage as your URL. Since that's a totally different problem, I'd remove the update and ask a new question to keep the question focused to one topic so it's useful for future visitors.

Comment: Will update the code - changed the url - it is looking better now