# Playwright locator().evaluateAll - understand code tooltip

Tags: typescript, generics, promise, playwright

I would like to understand the signature of `page.locator("line-item").evaluateAll();`
For this line

```js
const lineItems = await page.locator("line-item").evaluateAll(nodes =>{ ...});
```

the tooltip in VS Code shows this info

```js
Locator.evaluateAll<A>(B): Promise<...>
```

For brevity

1. `<A>` stands for `<any[], SVGElement | HTMLElement>`
2. `(B)` stands for `(pageFunction: PageFunctionOn<C>)`
3. `<C>` stands for `<(SVGElement | HTMLElement)[], void, any[]>`

To my understanding A = `<any[], SVGElement | HTMLElement>` means that the function can be passed

- an array of any type `any[]` and
- a union type that is either an `SVGElement` or an `HTMLElement`

The argument B = `(pageFunction: PageFunctionOn<C>)` is of type `PageFunctionOn` and i assume this [type is meant](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/9771b1ee74dd1969857dd246fdd0f4e29c78fce9/packages/playwright-core/types/structs.d.ts#L42) (see line 42), but i do not understand this type definition:

```js
export type PageFunctionOn<On, Arg2, R> 
        = string | ((on: On, arg2: Unboxed<Arg2>) 
        => R | Promise<R>);
```

And finally C = `<(SVGElement | HTMLElement)[], void, any[]>` means that `pageFunction` has three parameters:

1. the first parameter is a union type and either an array of `SVGElement` or an array of `HTMLElement`
2. the second parameter is void <-- this is confusing
3. the third parameter / or return type is an array of any type

#### Question

1. Is my understanding of A,B,C correct?
2. In [generate_types/overrides.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/9771b1ee74dd1969857dd246fdd0f4e29c78fce9/utils/generate_types/overrides.d.ts#L155) are two different signatures (see below) these are unclear to me.
3. Could you elaborate with some explanation using 2 or 3 different samples?

#### My efforts to understand the docs

I watched the section [Generics - TypeScript Crash Course](https://youtu.be/BCg4U1FzODs?t=2777) and used the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=76&pln=8&pc=1&q=107#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQIICcsEMCeAPACoB8AFDFKgLYDOAXIsQNoC6AlE624gN4AoRMMQQEdOABtUAOklxk5AORVadGVDgBlKFhhhFXREoA0iVfQ3bd%20wxyEis6EFiRhUAd0TY8%20chxkxSFwoSmp6ewBfAWkoRDAQGh8CRABeFHRkogSaACNULAoWAEYTACYTAGZOAVrQSFgERDoCAAlUSXkSMwBpChgAE24zXBwmHvYjHn4HYSCJaTkFZUGmU3MBsxVwxmMRnHsRRCcoFzdPbxwCf0CECBDyUawomPRmto75YjgAITwBtLvfDtTpwQg5fJYMxwXIAK1Q0AopUQLD4YFwNFQa1y-3WuDQTDKxUiNXmUlk8kUShawM%20cG%20f1wANS6xpIK%20v3%209iAA) to run this sample

```js
function sayHello<T, K>(id: T, arr: K[]): T[] {
    console.log('id: ', id, 'items: ', arr)
    return new Array().concat(arr)
}
let sayHelloToBrad = sayHello<number, object>(1, [{name: 'brad', age: 21}])
```

To my understanding the function `sayHello()` has two parameters `(id, arr)` of type `T` and `K[]`. The underlying type of T and K will be defined when the function is initialized / called.

I took a look at [this Type file](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/9771b1ee74dd1969857dd246fdd0f4e29c78fce9/utils/generate_types/overrides.d.ts#L155) which has two different signatures for `evaluateAll()` but here i have similar problem - for instance what does `R` mean?

```js
  evaluateAll<R, Arg, E extends SVGElement | HTMLElement = SVGElement | HTMLElement>
            (pageFunction: PageFunctionOn<E[], Arg, R>, arg: Arg): Promise<R>;

  evaluateAll<R, E extends SVGElement | HTMLElement = SVGElement | HTMLElement>
            (pageFunction: PageFunctionOn<E[], void, R>): Promise<R>;
```

I read [.NET docs about locator-evaluate-all](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-locator#locator-evaluate-all)

> Execute JavaScript code in the page, taking all matching elements as an argument.
>
> **Details**
>
> - Returns the return value of expression,
> - called with an array of all matching elements as a first argument,
> - and arg as a second argument.
>
> If expression returns a Task, this method will wait for the promise to resolve and return its value.
> If expression throws or rejects, this method throws.

```cs
// Tooltip
(Awaitable) Task<bool> ILocator.EvaluateAllAsync<bool>(
        string expression, 
        [object? arg = null]
)

// sample 
var located = Page.Locator("div"); // located contains all divs found
var moreThanTen = await located.EvaluateAllAsync<bool>(
                     "(divs, min) => divs.length > min", 
                     10);
// first argument 'expression' = (divs, min) => divs.length > min
// second argument 'arg' = 10
```

This was helpfull to get a first idea that `expression` can be a function like this

```js
var expression = function hasMoreElementsThenNumber(elements, arg){
     return (elements.length > arg)
}
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li")

console.log(`Is ${listItems.length;} > arg? ${expression(listItems,10)} `)
```

And that the locator result `located` will be passed as elements to the function.

Comment: This [answers  to `locator.evaluateAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76186992/819887) has one example how to use the method.